# ActiveAdmin doesn't take model translations on main menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

I have a weird bug with ActiveAdmin 0.4.3 regarding menu translations. I have a models.es.yml where I have all ActiveRecord translations. It works fine in actions, for example "Ad" is displayed as "Anuncio" in the show or edit views.

But in the main menu it still shows "Ad".

The weirder thing comes when I edit the file models.es.yml (adding a single space for example) and I reload the page the menu takes the translations, of course I can't do that in production.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can force a label into the menu with the following procedure:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ad do
    menu :label => "Anuncios"
end
```

Comment: That would make the work for now because I have only one locale, but I expect to have more locales in the future.